# How do you type an async express middleware function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, express, async-await, middleware

How do you define a return value for an express middleware that uses async/await?  I've tried a few different things but haven't had much luck.

I'm also trying to overload the Request object to allow req.user to be defined when we decode the JWT payload.

```
import { NextFunction, Request, RequestHandler, Response } from 'express'

const authenticate: RequestHandler = async (req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
  if (! req.headers.authorization) { return next(new ValidationError()) }
  const payload: IUserData = await decodeJwt(req.headers.authorization)
  req.user = payload
  return next()
}

export interface IUserRequest extends Request {
  user: IUserData
}

/* errors 
(req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler'.
  Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
    Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'IUserRequest'.
      Property 'user' is missing in type 'Request'.
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request` and `IUserRequest` types are incompatible, because `user` is missing in `Request`. The property likely doesn't present in `req` until it's assigned to it.

It should be:

```
export interface IUserRequest extends Request {
  user?: IUserData
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect that one thing to spawn all the other errors as well.

Comment: By the same token, how do you stop throwing errors because token can be string or undefined?  I'm trying to use it and I'm getting errors.    `const token = req.user.token as string` gives me `req.user may be undefined`

Comment: It could be typed properly if only RequestHandler was a generic, but since it isn't, I guess you just need to assert types like `req.user!.token`.